# Linux raw socket write error

Tags: linux, tcp, ip, raw-sockets

I have use connect with raw socket:

```
int rsfd=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_RAW,IPPROTO_TCP);
```

and connect:

```
connect (rsfd,(sockaddr *)&client,len);
```

but when i am trying to use write/send it is giving me error:

```
write(rsfd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
```

> Error: Invalid argument

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Do `socket` and `connect` return without errors? Did you check `errno`?

Comment: yes they are not returning any errors.

Comment: Please give a minimal complete example that shows the error.